# How do I get my Capybara spec to create database records, login with Google, and then see those records displayed?

Tags: database, selenium, port, capybara, poltergeist

**Question**: What do I need to set up in order to write RSpec/Capybara tests which involve logging in with Google and interacting with the database somehow (either through the app or in code), and then successfully see the results of those interactions reflected in the app?

Specifically, I want one spec which does the following:

1. Create some `Projects` in the database
2. Navigate to the projects index (which will redirect me to Google for login)
3. Login through Google and allow my app access
4. Assert the `Projects` appear listed on the page

And another like this:

1. Navigate to the projects index (which will redirect me to Google for login)
2. Login through Google and allow my app access
3. Click 'Add Project' (which redirects me to a form)
4. Fill in the form and hit save (which redirects me to the index)
5. Assert the newly created `Project` appears on the page

The tests I've written to do this don't work.

**First attempt** (using 'standard' RSpec/Capybara/Selenium)

I've got `js: true` set on the appropriate `describe` blocks and toggle `WebMock` connection settings around each spec.  The last step of both tests fail.  The first one just doesn't show any projects.  I can `puts Project.count` just before the assertion that there are some projects appearing on the page, and I'll see a non-zero number, but nothing is displayed on the page nonetheless.  The last step of the second test results in an internal server error.

Based on this it seemed like there were some database-related issues

**Second attempt** (adding some database configurations)

Added `DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation` to `spec_helper` as well as the following code insed the `RSpec` configuration block:

```
config.around :each, js: true do |spec|
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
    DatabaseCleaner.start
    WebMock.allow_net_connect!

    spec.run

    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    DatabaseCleaner.clean
    WebMock.disable_net_connect! :allow => %r{/((__.+__)|(hub/session.*))$}
end
```

Same result as the first attempt.

**Third Attempt** (using Poltergeist instead of Selenium)

I installed `phantomjs`, added `poltergeist` to my Gemfile, and bundled.  In `spec_helper` I required `capybara/poltergeist` and set `Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist`.  This seemed to make things worse, as I could no longer get through the step of allowing access as clicking that button seemed to do nothing (either that, or the driver simply wasn't clicking the button).

**Additional Info**
The first thing I had to do to get my tests to even begin to work was to fix the port on the Capybara server since the Google API requires a pre-registered callback URL.  This was accomplished easily enough by setting `Capybara.server_port = <some_number>` in `spec_helper.rb`.

My controller specs pass just fine, and when I use the app in real life it works fine.  Here's (a slightly modified version of) the code for the first test:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe 'Projects', js: true do
    it 'shows a list of projects' do
        Project.create!(name: "foo")
        visit projects_path
        fill_in "Email", with: "validemail@gmail.com"
        fill_in "Password", with: "password"
        click_on "Sign in"
        sleep 1.5 and click_on "Allow access" if page.has_content? "Allow access"
        page.should have_content("foo")
     end
end
```

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: Unable to find "<name of my new project>" in "<the text of the Google page where the user is supposed to click 'Allow access'>"

Comment: What you can try is checking ```Project.all``` to make sure model is created. If it is created, it should be a problem with application.